# External bluetooth dongle not working with macbook pro 13 inch early 2015

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, bluetooth

I have macbook pro 13 inch early 2015

it's bluetooth is out of order since long.
[image: Bluetooth not working]

I got this bluetooth dongle from local market

[image: blutetooth 5 dongle]

This shows up in my usb tree

[image: BT device in usb tree]

but i still cannot see it in HCI controller

[image: No bt device in HCI]

i tried going through this guide https://www.atpeaz.com/using-unsupported-bluetooth-4-0-usb-dongle-with-os-x/ but it didn't work as well.

I have also tried reset SMC some time ago, that didn't work as well.

any idea on how to make this work ?

Comment: Does the dongle packaging **specifically** state it is compatible with macOS? Which macOS version is installed on your MacBook Pro?

Comment: @jaume Yes it mentions MacOS on backside in compatible operating systems.

Comment: Which is your macOS version? Which app is the "Host Controller Selector" screenshot from?

Comment: @jaume macOS Catalina
Version 10.15.5

Host Controller Selector it is bluetooth explorer app comes with developer tools for macos.